# bash - colon in array key name

Tags: arrays, bash, key

I'm trying to write a script in bash that does the same things for several instances of the same application - running on different ports. My current approach was to use an array like so:

```
INSTANCES=('localhost:50010' 'localhost:50011' 'localhost:50012')
for INSTANCE in ${INSTANCES[@]}; do
  A["$INSTANCE"]="$(do stuff with $INSTANCE)"
  B["$INSTANCE"]="$(do more stuff with $INSTANCE)"
done
```

Bash seems to reject this since there is a colon in the array key name:

```
bash: localhost:50010: syntax error in expression (error token is ":50010")
```

I guess that's got something to do with the **[Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)** or something similar. Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying without manipulating the content of `$INSTANCE`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colon is very much accepted as array key name for associative array.

You just need to declare your associative arrays first:

```
declare -A A B
```

Comment: Sometimes it's the most obvious and simple things that can drive you crazy. Thanks.